# Why is base class method called instead of derived class method?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Expecting "Hello from the derived." but getting "Hello from the base.".

```
class Program
{
    interface IBase
    {
        void Method();
    }

    public class Base: IBase
    {
        public virtual void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from the base.");
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public virtual new void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from the derived.");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBase x = new Derived();
        x.Method();
    }
}
```

So why isn't the derived class's method called.  And more importantly, how can I get the derived classes method to get called without casting x to the Derived type?

In my actual application, IBase has several other related methods and Derived only replaces two of the methods in IBase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use the `new` modifier you are specifically saying that the method is not part of the virtual dispatch chain for that hierarchy, so calling the method by the same name in the base class will not result in redirection to the child class.  If you mark the method with `override` instead of `new` then you will see the virtual dispatch that you are expecting to see.

You will also need to remove `virtual` from the derived class's method as you cannot mark an `override` method as `virtual` (it already is).

If you really don't want to override the method then it may be more appropriate, in your situation, to not use inheritance at all.  You may simply want to use interfaces exclusively:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

public class A : IFoo
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am A, hear me roar!");
    }
}

public class B : IFoo
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am B, hear me roar!");
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IFoo foo = new A();
    foo.Foo();

    foo = new B();
    foo.Foo();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit . . .");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: You're suggested solution isn't buildable.  The compiler complains "Cannot override member 'Program.Base.Method()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override.

Comment: The base method has to be marked `virtual` and the derived method `override`.

Comment: @estimpson did you remove `virtual` from the base class's definition, because you should only remove it from the derived class's definition.

Comment: Correction, I now see what you were suggesting. I didn't fully understand your explanation regarding the "virtual dispatch chain for that hierarchy." But that gave me something to investigate for a better understanding.  Thanks.

Comment: I prefer an answer that I discovered somewhat by accident.  I removed "virtual" from all the method declarations, left "new" on the derived class, and changed the derived class declaration to be `Derived : Base, IBase`.  This makes more sense to me because Base doesn't necessarily "know" that it's member functions will be overridden.  However, Derived "knows" that it is replacing an existing method from Base.  Any thoughts on which solution makes more sense?

Comment: @estimpson No, that doesn't make sense if `Derived` is extending `Base`.  The entire point of extending the class is this context is to override that method.  If you don't want to override the method then the proper thing to do is cut out inheritance altogether.  Have classes `A` and `B`, neither extending the other, and both implementing the interface.  Given that you seem to really not want to override the method, that seems to be more appropriate for you.

Comment: @Servy My interface has 10 methods.  Base implements all of them.  Derived needs to override the behavior of 2 of them.  The "virtual"/"override" pattern requires me to either mark all of my base class methods as "virtual" or go back any time I want to override them in a derived class.  By saying instead that Derived inherits from Base and implements IBase, I can create "new" methods in Derived for only the methods I want to change without touching the base class.  I still think this makes sense, but if not, what is the purpose of the "new" keyword?

Comment: @estimpson In that case you really do want to have the derived class overriding methods of the base class.  In that example, all of the methods should be marked as virtual, and all of the derived class methods should override them.  You shouldn't be using `new` at all here.  `new` is a way of saying that the method has no relation whatsoever to the member of the same name in the base class; it's just coincidence that they have the same name. I almost never use it; if the members aren't related I give them unique names. Here they clearly are related, so they shouldn't be marked `new`.

Answer (score 3):

This is basic [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) at work.

For the behavior you're looking for, you would need to set your derived method to override the inherited method:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from the derived.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword instead of `virtual new` in your child class.

Therefore, your code should look like:

```
class Program
{
    interface IBase
    {
        void Method();
    }

    public class Base: IBase
    {
        public virtual void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from the base.");
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public override void Method() // The magic happens here!
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from the derived.");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IBase x = new Derived();
        x.Method();
    }
}
```

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the `new` keyword is used to hide the parent method, which is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @SteveHémond I see no need for him to add the code to show the changing of one word, but it would be nice for the answer to correctly mention which words needs to be corrected (new and virtual) or to explain why it matters.

Comment: @Servy : You're right. That's exactly why I wanted him to show the corrected code : To desambiguate his answer.

Comment: @SteveHémond His answer isn't ambigous, it's just wrong.  He said replace virtual, he needs to replace both `virtual` and `new`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'll spend some time reading up on the real purpose of the "new" keyword.  BTW, I found a slightly different solution.  If I change my Derived class definition to "public class Derived : Base, IBase" it also works (with new virtual methods for both Methods).

Answer (score 1):

`new` keyword creates a new method and says that the base method is hidden. But it is only for consumers of your derived class, since the base class code does not know anything about it.

`override` keyword overrides the base class implementation with a new one.

```
class Program
{
    interface IBase
    {
        void Method();
    }

    public class Base: IBase
    {
        public virtual void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from the base.");
        }
    }

    public class Derived : Base
    {
        // the next line was changed.
        public override void Method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from the derived.");

            // note that if you want to call the original implementation, you do it like this:
            base.Method();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base x = new Derived();
        x.Method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new'd Method in Derived only exists in a Derived instance, where it effectively hides the base implementation.

But IBase type only knows the Base's implementation, so it calls that.

To answer your question, to call the derived's implementation you'd do:

```
Derived d = new Derived();
d.Method();
((IBase)d).Method();

//Prints:
//Hello from the derived.
//Hello from the base.
```